# If command reach timeout execute other command

Tags: ubuntu, cron, shutdown, zenity

I'm trying to set up a script for my school's computer that switches them off automatically at the end of the day (since most teachers forgot them on).

I thought to send a zenify warning box to inform the user that the PC is going to switch off and, if the user do not confirm in 1 minute, the PC shuts down.

I know the existence of the timeout command, but in this case I want to call `sudo shutdown -h now` if the `zenity` command do not return in 60 seconds.

I was trying to do something like

`timeout 60 --onTimeout="sudo shutdown -h now" zenity --warning --text="This PC is going to shut down in a minute if you DO NOT press the OK button."`

The command would be executed in a cron script.

So, **the question is**: *How can I execute a command when the zenity program timeout?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to check the exit status and make a decision based on that. The [manual for GNU timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) says that

> If  the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit with status 124.

So, in a shell script, you'd do something like this:

```
timeout 60 zenity ...
if [ $? = 124 ] ; then
    echo it timed out, do something...
else
    echo didn't time out
fi
```

Though, it appears that [zenity supports a timeout in itself](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/usage.html.en), so you don't need an external timeout:

```
zenity --timeout 60 --warning --text="Shutdown in 60"
if [ $? = 5 ] ; then
    sudo shutdown -h now
fi
```

---

Even if using Zenity's own timeout, it doesn't seem to show the time remaining. However, it does have a progress bar mode that could be used to convey a sense of impending doom. Something like this would display a timer counting down from 60 with a progress bar filling up at the same time:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout=60
for (( i=0 ; i <= $timeout ; i++ )) do 
    echo "# Shutdown in $[ $timeout - $i ]..."
    echo $[ 100 * $i / $timeout ]
    sleep 1
done | zenity  --progress --title="Shutting down automatically..."  \
    --window-icon=warning --width=400 --auto-close

if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
    echo timeout passed
else 
    echo cancel was pressed or zenity failed somehow
fi
```